# Trying to loop through an JSON object and output it using HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to loop through [this](http://design.propcom.co.uk/buildtest/accordion-data.json) JSON data and output the data to an accordion like this:
http://alexthorpe.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/accordion_with_css.jpg but it's not working.

This is what I have so far:
   HTML:

```
<div class="accordion">
            <div class="slide">
                <h3></h3>
                <div class="accordion-info">
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.accordion-info').hide();
    $('.slide > h3').click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('http://design.propcom.co.uk/buildtest/accordion-data.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });

});
```

This is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zEWgqB).

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @Optional I am trying to loop through this [JSON](http://design.propcom.co.uk/buildtest/accordion-data.json) object

Comment: You need to itereate thru again the 'blocks' which is an array as part of your  response.. As each block has content  and heading attribute, which you can append to your div. Simple :)

Comment: check this out working jsfiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/ksrawat/brzvweh5/

Answer (score 1):

**HTML CODE**

Here I will be using template format it will be easier to add or remove child elements

```
<!-- Display Accordion -->
<div>
   <h1>Jquery Accordion</h1>
   <div class="accordion"></div>
</div>
<!-- Template for each slide item -->
<div rel="template">
   <div class="block">
      <h3 class="heading"></h3>
      <div class="content"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://design.propcom.co.uk/buildtest/accordion-data.json', function(data) {
        // To empty the existing item
        // $('.accordion').empty();

        // Iterate block
        $.each(data.blocks, function(k, v) {
            // Make use of jquery clone
            var new_block = $('[rel=template]').find('.block').clone();
            new_block.find(".heading").html(v['heading']);
            new_block.find(".content").html(v['content']);

            // Append the each item
            $('.accordion').append(new_block)
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: @JafarOcean the same code in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sivarajs/n820mh6j/1/ it's not secure because we're try to access http over https

Answer (score 0):

Since I wanted to avoid calling data from a different server, copied the data here and this is how it loops

```js
var jsonData = 
{
 "blocks": [
  {
   "heading": "Section 1",
   "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore sed aliquam vitae fugit odit voluptate eligendi, blanditiis quasi nobis reiciendis! Rem maiores reprehenderit animi aliquam inventore vel adipisci delectus itaque! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore sed aliquam vitae fugit odit voluptate eligendi, blanditiis quasi nobis reiciendis!"
  },
  {
   "heading": "Section 2",
   "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore sed aliquam vitae fugit odit voluptate eligendi, blanditiis quasi nobis reiciendis! Rem maiores reprehenderit animi aliquam inventore vel adipisci delectus itaque! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore sed aliquam vitae fugit odit voluptate eligendi, blanditiis quasi nobis reiciendis! Rem maiores reprehenderit animi aliquam inventore vel adipisci delectus itaque!"
  },
  {
   "heading": "Section 3",
   "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
  }
 ]
};
var json = jsonData.blocks;
  for (var key in json) {
       if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          console.log(json[key].heading);
          console.log(json[key].content);
       }
    }
```

Comment: thanks is there a way to use the url instead of copy and pasting the json data?

Comment: you can use url like you are doing but not in jsfiddle or your codepen because of cors/different protocol of the url you are using. If the url is returned from same server you are running the html, then you can use it

Comment: No.your code is correctly fetching json data. See here working example of cors enabled url http://jsfiddle.net/esmufhzb/